# Getting null pointer exception when loading data from sqlite database to baseadapter in android

Tags: android, sqlite, nul

I having a listview in which i have fetch the values from sqlite the values which i have fetched from sqlite are stored in base adapter where i have used condition to check the strings has values or not but still it shows me the null pointer exception even  i have added the not null in the condition but it didn't works and here is my code:

```
 final Daybooklist m = daybooklists.get(position);
    if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer") && m.getUsertype() != null) {
        day_name.setText(m.getName());
        day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
        day_type.setText(m.getType());
        if (m.getName().startsWith("no") && m.getName() != null) {
            day_name.setText(" ");
        } else if (m.getDescription().startsWith("no") && m.getDescription() != null) {
            day_description.setText(" ");
        }
        day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountin());

    } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer") && m.getUsertype() != null) {
        day_name.setText(m.getName());
        day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
        day_type.setText(m.getType());
        if (m.getName().startsWith("no") && m.getName() != null) {
            day_name.setText(" ");
        } else if (m.getDescription().startsWith("no") && m.getDescription() != null) {
            day_description.setText(" ");
        }
        Log.e("amountout",m.getAmountout());
        day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
    } else {
        day_name.setText(m.getName());
        day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
        day_type.setText(m.getType());
        if (m.getName().startsWith("no") && m.getName()!=null) {
            day_name.setText(" ");
        } else if (m.getDescription().startsWith("no") && m.getDescription() != null) {
            day_description.setText(" ");
        }
        Log.e("amountout",m.getAmountout());
        day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());

    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.startsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at codingtown.coconut.daybook.adapter.Daybooklist_adapter.getView(Daybooklist_adapter.java:96)
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                    at codingtown.coconut.libraries.expandablelistview.ExpandableHeightListView.onMeasure(ExpandableHeightListView.java:34)
```

Comment: Issue is not with your "m" variable. Its m.getUsertype() which is returning null object. Verify if you are populating Daybooklist properly and assigning UserType properly.Check it like this if(m.getUsertype() != null && m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")). Null check never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this structure

```
if(m.getUsertype() != null && !m.getUsertype().isEmpty()) {


 if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")
 {
 }
 else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")
 {
 }
 ....
 }
```

Comment: You can also use `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getUsertype()){` instead of `if(m.getUsertype() != null && !m.getUsertype().isEmpty()) {`